# Relationship between acyclic models and universal $\delta$-functors

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-functors

(An elementary version of) The acyclic models theorem more-or-less says that natural transformations between the zeroth homology of a free functor taking values in $\mathsf{Ch}^+_\bullet(\mathsf A)$ to the zeroth homology of a parallel acyclic functor are in bijection with (chain) homotopy classes of natural transformations: $$[F,G]\cong \mathsf{Nat}(H_0F,H_0G).$$

A universal $\delta$-functor $F_\bullet:\mathsf{A}\rightarrow \mathsf{B}$ is a $\delta$-functor for which giving a morphism $\tau_\bullet:F_\bullet\rightarrow G_\bullet$ of $\delta$-functors is equivalent to merely giving $\tau_0$. In other words (assuming $\delta$-functors from $\mathsf A$ to $\mathsf B$ and their morphisms constitute a category $\delta$, we have a bijection $$\mathsf{Hom}_\delta(F_\bullet,G_\bullet)\cong \mathsf{Nat}(F_0,G_0).$$

For both concepts, "extending from the zeroth level" seems to play a central role. I'm trying to understand precisely what is the formal (and informal) relationship  between them.

[This MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2985/derived-functors-vs-universal-delta-functors/3065#3065) may be relevant, but I'm unable to understand the answers fully, so if they help, please explain them in detail.

> What is the big picture here?